# Xcode 8 Cannot define category for undefined class 'NSString'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode8.2

How to resolve this error in Xcode 8.2.1?

```
Cannot define category for undefined class 'NSString'
```

This error is not coming in Xcode 7.2. I referred to some older posts but didn't help. Still getting same errors.

[image]

Comment: NSString is replaced with String!

Comment: Can you show any implementation concerning this issue?

Comment: I am able to reproduce issue by creating new framework project and adding any new file single file. This steps cause above error

Comment: `NSString` is in `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`. Did you perhaps forget to import this class? (In your categories)

Comment: I did imported that. But I am getting error saying "Foundation module not found."